# Padding, offset, or position in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-layout, swiftui-view

I’m trying to position a circle to have its center sitting on top of a rectangle like this. The diameter of the circle doesn't have to be the same width as the rectangle.

[image]

What I’m trying to understand is what is the best and most practical way to accomplish this? Should I be using padding, offset, or position in this case and would it hold for different devices/screen sizes? It seems like any of them can be used but which one is more ideal?

Here’s what I have with using `padding`. I can increase the bottom padding to achieve what I want but not sure if that’s the best way.

```swift
Rectangle()
    .fill(Color.gray)
    .frame(width: 85, height: 175)
    .overlay(
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.black)
            .frame(width: 120)
            .padding(.bottom, 50)
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is possible approach - just to use alignment without hardcoding offsets/positions.

Demo prepared with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

```
var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.gray)
        .frame(width: 85, height: 175)
        .overlay(
            Circle()
              .stroke(Color.black,
                    style: StrokeStyle(
                         lineWidth: 2,
                         lineCap: .round,
                         lineJoin: .miter,
                         miterLimit: 0,
                         dash: [5, 10],
                         dashPhase: 0
                    ))
              .frame(width: 85, height: 85)
              .alignmentGuide(.top) { $0[VerticalAlignment.center] } // << this !!
        , alignment: .top)    // and this !!
}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

For shapes a good approach would be to combine overlay and offset like so:

```
Rectangle()
    .fill(Color.red)
    .frame(width: 100, height: 180)
    .overlay(
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))
            .frame(width: 100)
            .offset(y: -90)
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Would you still use offset or one of the others if overlaying an image onto a shape?

Comment: Yes, overlay/offset work well together regardless of the views they are applied to